# What is the minimal delay between gates on IBM devices?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

Suppose I create the very simple circuit

```
OPENQASM 2.0;
include "qelib1.inc";
qreg q[1];
x q[0];
barrier q[0];
x q[0];
```

and submit it to an IBM backend. How do I find the buffer time between the end of the first `X` and the beginning of the second `X` for a given backend? I've seen the number `~10 ns` thrown around in the literature (see [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1807.08768) above Fig. 1), but this value is not displayed in the calibration data for a device.

Just for clarify, I am NOT referring to the duration of `X` but the duration of time between the `X` pulses even "when it appears to be 0."

If there's a way to obtain it via Qiskit on a per-calibration basis, that's even better, but just a reference which verifies that `10 ns` is a reasonable value would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: The minimal delay between gates on IBMQ chips is $0$ nano-seconds.

Longer answer:

The `barrier` operation is not a hardware operation, it just give instructions to the compiler to schedule the circuit correctly. As such, its duration is $0$ nano-seconds as it is never executed on the hardware. You can check this on [luciano answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16731/1386): the `barrier` operation is not present in the generated schedule.

If your question was rather "what it is the minimum non-zero delay between two gates on IBM chips", the answer is `dt` = $\frac{2}{9}$ nano-seconds on the most recent backends. You can recover this value for each backend with

```
from qiskit import schedule, QuantumCircuit, transpile, IBMQ
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider()
backend = provider.get_backend("ibmq_armonk")

dt = backend.configuration().dt
print(f"dt = {dt*1e9:.2f} ns")
```

Pulses duration should be a multiple of `16dt` but delay duration can be any multiple of `dt`.

Answer (score 3):

Not an expert here, but my impression is that the rotations are scheduled one after the other one, with no delay.

Taking your example:

```
from qiskit import schedule, QuantumCircuit, transpile, IBMQ
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider()

circuit = QuantumCircuit(1)
circuit.x(0)
circuit.barrier(0)
circuit.x(0)
circuit_t = transpile(circuit, backend)
```

If we schedule that one on `ibmq_lima`:

```
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_lima')
print('lima openpulse support:', backend.configuration().open_pulse)

schedule(circuit_t, backend).draw(backend=backend, time_unit='ns')
```

[image]

It seems to me that the distance between pulses is not 10ns.